# how can i get this box to accept my question? Question - VBA error GOTO challenge

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, goto

I am trying to use "Error goto" and I think its not difficult.

I am trying to get the 2nd VBA code to...
on error, jump to "Sheets("RISA").Select" if the find within the column is an error

If it finds the "2" - it enacts  the select and delete

If it does not find the "2" it "jumps over the Select and delete"
and ignores it.

how would i use an error handler for this, and the "On Error GoTo -1' is confusing.

Can anyone assist?

This is not my code..this is what i am trying to add to my code below it.

```
On Error GoTo errorHandler1
    Windows(myFile).Activate
    Sheets(secondDetailTab).Activate
    'bunch of code
errorHandler1:

    'bunch of code
    
    On Error GoTo -1
    On Error GoTo errorHandler2
    Windows(myFile).Activate
    Sheets(secondDetailTab).Activate
    'bunch of code
errorHandler2:

    'bunch of code
```

this is my code.......

```
Columns("X:X").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


Sheets("RISA").Select
```

Comment: A much better approach is to test if the find succeeded: `Dim rng As Range`, `Set rng = Columns("X:X").Find(What:="2", ....)`, then `If Not rng Is Nothing`, `Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete`, `Else`, `Windows(myFile).Activate`, `Sheets(secondDetailTab).Activate`, `End If`...

Comment: thank you, i get the idea. I am trying to get your code into my vba box, its partially red.
 Sub testfind()


Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Columns("X:X")
Find(What:="2", ....)
then
If Not rng Is Nothing
Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete
Else
Windows(myFile).Activate
Sheets(secondDetailTab).Activate
End If


End Sub.  wow..these text boxes are.......difficult

Comment: You're missing a `.` between `Columns("X:X")` and `Find`. You also have to specify the remaining arguments for `Find` (`After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues` and so on).

Comment: Dim rng As Range,
Set rng =,
Columns("X:X").Find(What:="2", ....),
then,
If Not rng Is Nothing,
Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete,
Else,
Windows(myFile).Activate,
Sheets(secondDetailTab).Activate,
End If,